# VueJS animation after array replace

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, vue.js

I would like to animate an array replacement. I have a case when my array is being replaced and I have to animate it (transition from right to the left). I am not sure if transition-group will work here (no pushing and slicing). How to do this?

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array:  [1,2,3]
  },
  mounted:  function()  {
     setTimeout(() => this.array = [4,5,6], 5000)
  }

})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="item in array">{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

Code example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyzYaV?page=1&

Regards

Comment: You need to be more precise on how you want them to be replaced. one set (123) goes out one side and the other set comes in on the other side? Would the two set be shown at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

It will work just fine with `transition-group` as transitions are kicked off any time you change the array, whether it's push/slice or a full replacement.

This is pretty much [straight from the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions).

```
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="list"  mode="out-in" tag="p">
    <p v-for="item in array" v-bind:key="item" class="list-item">{{item}}</p>
  <transition-group>
</div>


.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0.4;
  float: right;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```